# Difference between Windows and Mac OS X with (HTML) DL DT DD as a list

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/mbekX/

Under Windows with Chrome, Opera, IE8 and FF all working fine:

```
X TEXT
X TEXT
X TEXT
```

But with Safari and FF on OSX I get like this:

```
X TEXT
  X TEXT
    X TEXT
```

Can anybody help me here?

I can fix it in OSX with set dd with a fix height, but the dd-tag have multilines too. So this ist not possible for it.

ADD OSX-IMAGE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2LjF.png
Under Windows all green rectangle are directly below

Comment: What's about Safari on Windows?

Comment: Happens on FireFox on OSX too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `line-height` on `dd` and `dt` elements to the same as the `height` of your `dt` elements.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbekX/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the height and width on some empty `<dt>` elements to a specific size that is larger than the "row" you're attempting to put on. Couple that with `float:left` and you get the effect you see here. Basically the line height is less than the 16px height you've set those dt elements to. You could increase the `line-height` of the `<dl>` until the dt elements no longer stagger. I would recommend `line-height: 1.5;` at least. But this issue sort of resolves itself if you have content in each of your `<dt>` elements and you don't set it's height, just like the `<dt>X</dt>` element. And you wouldn't have definition data (`<dd>`) without a definition term (`<dt>`) in your definition list (`<dl>`), right?